# correct facebook open graph type to use for an online game?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Anyone know which is the correct open graph type to use for an online game?

Here is a list but none seem appropriate

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/

I guess object type, but that doesn't seem very specific!

How about more types, I can think of a few just of the top of my head:

Games, Art, Online Service, Blog (to differentiate from website), picture, map ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to create a custom story type, which will allow you to specify your own open graph object type and action. You can read more about custom story types in [Facebook's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories/).

Comment: thanks for your answer, basically I have a html5 app on a webpage and want to do facebook SEO using the og parameters and want to label the game correctly, not sure I need a story for this, maybe I will use them later in game play, however within a facebook app.

Comment: Through the same interface you can just create a custom object and use that in your OG tags on your page. That'll work out of the box with the Facebook like button and other social plugins.